# Is IBM Rational different from IBM Rational Rose?

Tags: ibm-rational, rational-rose

As per my knowledge Rational is a testing tool and Rational Rose is a modelling tool.

Answer (score 3):

Rational is a company that makes tools for software development life cycle. Rational Rose is one such tool built by Rational.

Rational is now part of IBM. See www.rational.com.

Answer (score 2):

Rational Software (a company that was acquired by IBM about 7 years ago) and remains a brand in the IBM Software Group. The Rational portfolio is quite broad concentrating on overall Application Lifecycle Management and System Management solutions. Testing, Quality Management, Configuration Management, Mobile Development, Requirements Management, Change Management, Agile Development, Mainframe Development, Enterprise Modernization and much more.

Answer (score 0):

There is IBM Rational Test Real Time , and it is used for module and unit tests , as well as performance and memory profiling . it is mainly a testing tool . know nothing about rational Rose .